# database server on domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, active-directory, domain

Are there any significant drawbacks to joining a SQL Server machine to the domain (i.e. security, performance, etc)?  Our box is currently off the domain so we just manage users locally, but we were thinking that security may be a little stronger with it off the domain.

**Edit** - Forgot to mention, this is a database server for a public-facing web app ... not sure if this changes the answer (the web app is in its own DMZ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it to the domain. Performance issues due to adding a domain would be so minute if anything at all.

Comment: Plus you can still use local users/groups, and domain users/groups, cross domain trusts, apply GPO and all the other fun that comes along with AD.

Comment: BTW, it's a db server for a public-facing web app.  The web app is in its own DMZ, but not sure if this makes a difference (from a security standpoint).